# Play Store Billing : Get last subscription renewal date

Tags: java, android, play-billing-library

I am currently trying to fix the following edge case in my app, without using the "Google Play Android Developer API" :

1. User buys Subscription(e.g. 1st of January)
2. Several Subscription renewals occur
3. User cancels his subscription(e.g. on the 15th of March)
4. User still has access to the subscription content, until the next billing period (e.g the 1st of March)

I am having difficulties doing so because whenever I call the `queryPurchases()` on my `BillingClient` object I always get the same data for `orderId` (Google states that the order ID should change based on the renewal recurrance number [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html) ) and `purchaseTime` stay the same, no matter if `queryPurchases(SkuType.SUBS)` is called while the subscription is active or canceled (same behaviour occurs if I call the `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()`. I would love to solve this issue without having to mess with the "Google Play Android Developer API".Using it seems a bit overkill for something as simple as getting the date of the last successful subscription renewal or just how many successful renewals there were.